# i am using spring+hibernate and i m getting error : org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: hibernate, spring, richfaces

i am using spring+hibernate and i m getting error when i upload doc file using `rich:upload` component, doc is uploaded sucessfully but when i click ok it gives following error. The field is `byte[]` doc;

> `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException`:
>   could not insert:
>   [`com.eTender.model.UploadDoc`];
>   nested exception is
>   `org.hibernate.exception.DataException`:
>   could not insert:
>   [`com.eTender.model.UploadDoc`]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

```
public void fileUploadListner(UploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
    File imageFilePath = item.getFile();        
    uploadDocDataBean.setDocname(item.getFileName());
    uploadDocDataBean.setDocsize(String.valueOf(item.getFileSize()));
    InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFilePath);
    byte[] data = new byte[(int)imageFilePath.length()];
    fileInputStream.read(data, 0, (int)imageFilePath.length());
    fileInputStream.close();
    uploadDocDataBean.setDoc(data);
}
```